# Brightness control not working on Ubuntu in HP Victus Gaming Laptop

Tags: hp, brightness, compatibility

I'm new to Linux and recently set up a dual boot with Ubuntu (22.04.3 LTS Desktop) and Windows 11 (Home) on my Victus by HP Gaming Laptop 15-fbOxxx (8GB/512GB), AMD Ryzen 5 5600H with Radeon Graphics, 2023 model. I also experimented with Fedora (38 workstation and even 39), but encountered the same issue - my brightness control doesn't work. It seems there might be a compatibility issue between my laptop model and Linux. I've tried various solutions from forums and YouTube videos, but nothing has worked. Could someone suggest a better solution for fixing the "brightness control not working" issue? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.